# Passing a record value as an input to pull data from another table whose name contains that input value

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, dynamic-sql

I have a master table, **fc_master** that contains a column called **fc_id**. This column has values such as **fc_id1**,**fc_id2** and so on.
I also have corresponding *detail tables* for each of these *fc_ids* in different categories, namely
**category_1_fc_id1**, **category_2_fc_id1**, **category_1_fc_id2**,
**category_2_fc_id2**.

> This brings my total number of tables to 5, i.e fc_master, category_1_fc_id1, category_2_fc_id1, category_1_fc_id2, category_2_fc_id2.

I want to generate an `Oracle SQL` query that would allow you me provide a single fc_id as an input to automatically pull from the appropriate fc_id tables. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

> Please simplify/correct your table names...why use fc_id1 at one place
> and fc_id_1 at another place? Can you use fc_id1 in both places?  same
> for 2.
>
> Try to keep table names and column names independent of the data in
> fc_id and category_id so that code is static instead of dynamic SQL.
>
> Please redesign to use fc_master (single master) with fc_id and
> fc_detail (single detail) with fc_id and category_id. Repeat the
> primary keys of master table in detail table so that a single detail
> table is sufficient instead of 4.
>
> Optional - Use Partitioning as needed on fc_id (primary) as well as
> category_id (secondary) if data is too large.